# Variable for parameter to where clause of Linq to Entity Framework

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a query like so:

```cs
var labs = context.vw_Lab_Space.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(lab => lab.Lab_Name.ToLower().Contains(text) || lab.Lab_Owner_Name.ToLower().Contains(text)
                || lab.Lab_Owner_Email.ToLower().Contains(text) || lab.Region_Code.ToLower().Contains(text)
                || lab.Country_Code.ToLower().Contains(text) || lab.Country_Name.ToLower().Contains(text)
                || lab.Site_Code.ToLower().Contains(text) || lab.Site_Name.ToLower().Contains(text)
                || lab.Building_Code.ToLower().Contains(text) || lab.Building_Name.ToLower().Contains(text))
```

And this compiles/runs properly.  I do the same query in multiple places, so I figured I'd extract that query.  If I do this though:

```cs
Func<vw_Lab_Space, bool> whereQuery = lab => lab.name.....
var labs = context.vw_Lab_Space.AsNoTracking()
             .Where(whereQuery)
```

then it compiles fine, but I get a runtime error saying that an object is not set.  Why can't I extract that query?

In the larger scheme that where clause is much more complex and so I wanted to extract the logic to a function that returned something of that type so it could get used without repeating the same code over and over.

Comment: To my understanding, the problem is not with extracting the predicate to make reusable, but I think it has to do with where you are invoking it from. As you mentioned you are getting error saying _an object is not set_, are you sure none of the objects involved are null?

Comment: If you are using LINQ to Entities then you need to use the `Queryable.Where` that takes an `Expression`, not a `Func`, as a `Func` is compiled code and can't be translated to SQL by the provider. Change the type of `whereQuery` to `Expression<Func<vw_Lab_Space,bool>>`.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage.  That was the problem.